# Searching in Slingshot causes Wingpanel Crash

Tags: wingpanel, slingshot, crash

Whenever I type anything into Slingshot, both Slingshot and Wingpanel freeze, crash, and reload.

Noticed this after uninstalling Epiphany, am I not supposed to uninstall it? I have reinstalled Epiphany and it still crashes.